How can I have seperate functionality in development and release builds in sveltekit?
What i am trying to do is have a some debug tools that are present in development builds, eg. yarn run dev but are not accessible in release builds, eg. yarn run build
thanks.
I have done some googling, but i couldn't find anything.
Sorry if I phrased my problem weirdly.

You can e.g. either define a replacement constant via Vite's define or use static environment variables.
Via define:
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig((cfg) => ({
    define: {
        VITE_DEV: cfg.mode === 'development',
    },
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
}));

// src/app.d.ts
declare global {
    // To prevent type errors when using TS
    declare const VITE_DEV: boolean;

    namespace App {
        ...
    }
}

Then on a page:
<script lang="ts">
    import DebugTools from './debug-tools.svelte';
</script>

<!-- [regular content] -->

{#if VITE_DEV}
    DEBUG MODE
    <DebugTools />
{/if}


Via environment variables:
<script lang="ts">
    import DebugTools from './debug-tools.svelte';
    import { PUBLIC_DEBUG_MODE } from '$env/static/public';
</script>

<!-- [regular content] -->

{#if PUBLIC_DEBUG_MODE == 'true'}
    DEBUG MODE
    <DebugTools />
{/if}

How the PUBLIC_DEBUG_MODE is set depends on the operating system.
You could e.g. set the variable directly in the package.json scripts section.
Note that if the variable is not defined, the build will fail.

Since in both cases the code is statically processed during the build process, the debug code (including the debug component import) can be automatically eliminated via tree shaking.
(For Svelte 5 there currently is a bug in that regard.)

This works thanks. are there any benefits to using environment variables over vite?

The variable is auto-generated by SvelteKit, so if the code is type checked, you don't have to declare it. It's also a bit more flexible since you can create a production build with dev tools enabled if you want to.

thanks for this. you've saved me a lot of time, i wish i had the rep to upvote you lol.
